# Decryption via Multi processing in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, parallel-processing, cryptography, multiprocessing

I have image data(210KB) that has been encrypted via RSA algorithm. I would like to decrypt that encrypted image data into Javascript using JSEncrypt. I was able to decrypt the image successfully, but it took around 10 seconds. So I thought to use the multiprocessing in Javascript  in which I want to use JSEncrypt functionality which is loaded in script.

How to use parallel processing in Javascript to speedup the processing. Or is there any other way to speedup the RSA decryption in Javascript?

Here is the sample code that I was trying for parallel processing in Javascript, but decrypt.decrypt was not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="D:\parallel.js"></script>
<script src="D:\jsencrypt.js"></script>
</head>
<script>

                            var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
                            decrypt.setPrivateKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+
'MIICXAIBAAKBgQCsqVGJUP6PhkjLSk3BkVRxg9ikUMZjN1BLS+HmEcjlVbkbsSuO\n'+
'K9uMmtZ7rkmL5aXcLxzNS1fexlr/ixvHeaK43KDXxob5drxcwCaRpadm4JjEKWiG\n'+
'ExbRUIorzFRqxCKFTwXRLerXhyFrfTqv/XNA2F94XwWBNuE8cs9S0ude9QIDAQAB\n'+
'AoGAPMzq/3XcDmJ1I9EojG9G0ypgkYw4MBv8VGeGRuQgYFHNe2jqM4hSKbMksCzx\n'+
'jSfzPhQBCnHroXEr/izYPWgh2m73737TYMHN5UVp9Kt/D1Kg/CUu6SDB6L6hbSYK\n'+
'YkWwifBtPzNcpF9cy7DPVaFGEeCkBroy86VcoQ/cVR7Vk8ECQQDapO2ve9Y332al\n'+
'iW7+2rFxSOeXwdofAlGpv378rAUIWrkGH11a4AtXInaPlty3td225IE6SyJu6trU\n'+
'4ookVNtZAkEAyikwrR6fDOqBPNrVKclfLjdFdfOhVIgdDXcD9lUhmcLJxF9NPKAW\n'+
'cVeCloFuw8eaHv8h2SrUt2itTw/N3ERY/QJAXP8XhbNTezJPM4uQJWAZZwjOUJMI\n'+
'VnYjC+NCfPAht9r2pa8DgxqWWDp1WT+eo5j8M8VfXc8FV04XQ8MTZL6fCQJBAKCY\n'+
'RCDiuHrsN6p+NOQzIjd2lOl0lu6uClZN+4nOaxjY0qv7AUJt8iYr3INvYuyIPfjt\n'+
'uJfqHH1u3G54IZMfgIkCQHBNzxAMO1upPNl5pbzw8KZyNavk9F+uYa3M54cpIw2H\n'+
'uO34E31dml3/77FAaCe8lIo2ezs+nbYVC2nNQZmGtGs=\n'+
'-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----');

var r = new Parallel(["qc7zdvF+HPwCiihmjy1frb4qDhAFf+PNhCdlVQdyLMNKm32j2N161fiPv/IHdXWqN1BSlkcPOXSTMkPCkMF9CHb3F5J7l6aw7fmwisptnMDhnlo4ukS04IiGpF+yu42bACXafHDD/qZsBygBDpdc26scb6bb21msUOGcO20oOyk=","Am4K7lP8gGI6dnbDWyZ4N6w5Foxq3IlUmSuGB1JW8MQqTKeKSoCPsCTqS3xrONLfyegUrQlDvONy/xKtryyuL3a8d5jQtmZ/mcn6D/B0llQsPDo3ie6XGRS++oDuNrMDwLbGZrG5j//eWXfaSRueGGxUHQd5dHTwjb+h1Vu/tK8=","AyHcazMAc5EwYMS8RObBM8c6EX5l7BSQd8V2BVUvCM+6QWZCqV888wx1prPxfjM0zOsPYUaSowMwbbtnoeyRuBX4StT8I0+Rkj/iTXOOU5BILpTi9/s7kVraY0TDHed5ZVNlkoAUrK30ny/VYe7MvjL48ecCD2LPqRGl+/Wejnc=","kzMr9po2vakHM6vuAro64cMAU810+z4HN2Jo4QK4+z+bwHWTA+dPHq6on5oub6d5Ko4fx00nZeBnp/m6oe14kyIiqrF0Z751fZv8uSxQ7f6ar1e6lgTqtOAaGW//6xTPyJlgYaqCO3EgQnuHvQYHa6T3SXWN9M9pwhARUwjOics=","gNuTWUUYI/PfNNBfIofHUQEiPct0nzPkVLJBSufZ5Ilm1YtnloUeeSNmBnvdT9GpLU6Giu5g/fCLGbianBsQ7SUi2ASCYDw6SngY8X4jRBjjFXE8ct7c9S3rhEKSmwPwZ6v7cbpXGTSStuhCYAXmhlV5HwHyxNaIxMRMgWpgLE8=","M5RpmPTrd6s/Ur72Q9N5yxPdP9wWbP1zM9EMpjTZlPgVTX2DQG5bgcEapovyszj+3ceUxmexTcRkSuzEQ9FChK1Tk8IjQMvpbiHNO9Bgx2HXabO/3f9NR+OaxHxZxKSV5pMH2TYofbjzPo5GJZ4CZpObeBEHTKjBgGI+PB/ysMk=","L+K2jMDGOvW3Qt9BI1BB0E4WKkUHS8G6SPAqeozes+DZ1I4FSB5BbAW+yNV/I+YvoLD29Unlym5YvjQBi9+XZlG5SBf9TdTsj8AjBTS3CiQobWtzqNmBAnwpW2zWyJPqO5mTC6DvOADkXHsrKtBqJZCjHdb3f92QTFOlLfuWmsw=","pdK1GSDZC3rTFX8gHeDPTQDnBFxL8h0e2qtxiPKNhuatnvqw180E9nqebjIS15faEKEBK4iWxPwR58s7rH1VCnzzTyUln1bOk1TfHiE5SPp66eb9fUvwUQkw/98B0KkwJ/eMK+nMqqh3eURTYm/AtdwSwk+AQpdhRJtp/TGr/3E=","BKl+JVLvfssawrsUBtOe9KdQ4HxXKzUk24RxqMnukUncGMsTaT5LBeo6ngD04UkREoYuU3YngbR/EcZhEynTeCNsvpo9LhvHKwcxTcfKfc2URFiPK65ZLI4WxdJ02iptGNr3FBk8GkbLCOB3m5LI7POZ2faTe0TejJFIftBjbiE=","pAnR9G7U5T2pIEgiZNluAk7/i2/aDXbBtxD1N3KjMn3eDDTweZzoqFbHua2LRFMQ9Rfe0X481YdmM7rcNjlQ0BstkdkaHcE5PNOVKrxQxW3IAERbcvFy6guc2hslh/SFVhMqS4cVXGd82U0Pq3C9togv3Jgt4S9l9GBG4jKGP08=","FDP5NUmMLVNQmmpxGil0llq/0QeLNTlscuMC4q8/d/NX+0N7nMUB8rSKMtRof7SV7Thr5+tC+VViN1oYL2Hc//gysIyS0OYXJWiOWlTLXp0J7dL133h7G7OWZHX+H6Pl3EcgCPvM5YdtHWX5UFOFeLlnZlxR24Euc1XqFVG1o+c=","qg+5Yd8Tl2FZSZgvLOu/V99NRReXZz/MLzFwXs7Mzt2CsHDMZg3ejLK7FBL2zV7tIwapJH20IxtfRoHismAX2IOFhv8WwC/z3CEMXQXYhJA4kFIVOtSpIbCbyfqMUP27jidoIRAgzmLJzzr4AwD3VTdaJZKUi/Uv/DIWXJTtmVk=","ECicU2n2hVSq4DccqxEIPr61rUoLx9e6n9U5AG86D/Vc2uLpHW6sIoOFeAq/ZCcL/j2cp4oPXxsDiT6mbvF7WtMEVhbpgj2faJQcMGbAds7ycjAlBmm9qzdsE4PH0oAUk2vt9lkCodG87w/+IUltYCbGUncmClBuLsZ9t8rPX2Q=","KpT0qqQ+JzVNkBGmg70D80DYnW47GY5zkF6+CxgW76SSRpou2YxgDfyvJVCVE1qSoow4NFPbEJZMTqDcR33RTYdU9EIykLw6XbLchf9y2tecUGtYjLYCzv3SelwusadNswFUOsm5xsKxafnXkvGIvKyy1XO3snSYT3KVfboYDxg=","KQEPX36hqwKFGSF1n266L8d86hhZgHoZfSTxhAOt7+lQH9obRJoZObEq3WflHbJUGhF/6DMgDbre5YgPCq/0dL6/2taRSr2PkG2DsPM4Pkf63YhN8l6l4D0PHSSZP218Mi1x7ag4aiiu/ZHYuGGi0tcTW8wIWjt5U9sy6v8SHFQ=","eczqC+Q5sB+RgrhInvKSswDH0W5cZ+/mGnjFO7dS8DZ1l77gdCN468REMMnmh9DfIrAIgl+71SdywGggN/ildgACirpGXZQr+1RvB8UtDAUlDusfM2vtwB+Az5lymv4QpUekv66hJL0G/kGU4Z7QXJc31vZz3yRutkZJmOINJ7M=","hlHbyfShPCPdpncZ30RGxvbfXqhjbnXu+EF9LBBeTbzrI0i/tLIKL5fBQ0XOQOsxbBqGqE6F0VCfaGR9hbuM0b6fCLRPrp2LK3LK4qhXJ+Ha8WYAfM0xk/5XHgMcaeNMa1H4NrPX3EL0F4BTsi35yTGFJ2KWOAsDVFDRbYN3sF4=","mual4G7H5zF449HY903kKSk4KADFj6+2Lwa4S0tw5aBCUGxAsm8awYHS4vcXd+AtHUDNtrZUyxC4COLOanNQTQ2fdnf+5lWqqUNTS0F+YnLNndGjBU2RdjvZfiMEhciuxIGb68sx74LfvM07F99jEtKnp1PBL2sttbquYEQztss=","Migv5dRzIFj3PiaHBasj+3N6yOybgDMpEoSkwOki70yytgkU4ovu6UUqlL6m5a5fCO61W4YwiT3vV9AcxlMfBwmxcxJUXOf6O24Mf1Ps24pasHHu8QJ9HAviEq2erLtN69ftI2H0P4mvdrw2zwdLmHQ1pwxlO14TajDmnGjuUkg=","Gz4iPZvRGVe9VFK5rzeXgE0FItidX9iPAbN8UBTgxZcZmugpKDpnsDb/Y9WYAgG1Nvf7jux3QbtTsjsgNACrCZ4trhqW+d8fADURFVkaLvGrUTCxIcvjcnDPuc7sBpqUSZ36mteMhFn42rwaLzmCOATa0/gbrxZjckh1yJr94hY=","BVCa1XEO+9kmA8sEpgvaOvJx2D6Dle/sXcXiHHmgaWXKwl0JKsRmuG/8uC8qLRGLDsXMDSPDZM9tSOFk+SZjNl7I+X3JU9hrTi5Jf/2aTePJObUNffODmqTw0H29Ht8kxzoXQZ8XTeym1VVzdSFZ2co/2UNeiP23wfCEY1Laso4=","BHxfRJHVfzPnsAOlEoURAYQwJYlD5JGxBO5Fimi5Eh2r/41ZdDu1CCDj1cPiNhExb6xJlpK30ViV+4XUjy2+Ajfj3kyQTpTLP/vfiTZB5B0H/N0VBF2R0rxhglX7bMecMpoNTwWtsRuERhZTObEQCBJMF/Q1SxuyRO0mczjiy44=","W/KypEoAM8ZRipsYtP4jjm4i+3rFUwsU+9Ckl7EueOpf44nBTK568h994CTu4/uvYTJ5Tb79GdKQ1uCggQrK2Qc7vXiB+D1AkxgAs1CHAIAGKwkIuDwAdWxt/BEUjJ86pjh6TWpvY83l1s2pd92sFvGpFegsHtqVoyUgkTu2Cb4=","V/C3DczOIiM0kTEdRGRz2cbJWzP0s5MnrdZOOee/Zgid67r+FFKEC2VxbtG6yiXr2KmcIgHr9KVdAudjXxmjIEe9Xp8570DiglYSg7u0vyyClHPfYCZu1GUIjN+eFg9DX8WgXAMsbLVSMhTrRMEXlEvpm2hT+7b2TDceC2Oj8Do=","qrK6efhqToF5Bb+Nc11byzcK7y3rDYewXOYwZ1f4N8r3VoC9QUXO63BzDK+iT7T4RpL/BzywC7cwTS1+ozeaImXgrVSyYVdkWp+dzHh8tKFLrOULCmaRx6kKrKGQTYgJUd6Ajq4gjYT0eXVO0eFfPfnxjF/4oi1oZyPgBFmPLXM=","G7Cq9G1O/YEGtdyJMVmmVDekuGp4zvnqaTY+lCslFWzwfYFCEpo6Oebn16o3Uzdr76kGlaZ3DRHTWlQ5fn8rhDNyYi53cggtdeb1UQQzKBPkXeEipMhAwRTsP/9HD6fVZueVxfOCuskbQU9CxVPk2hiR7qX+q39fXbNsit/JCnE=","nrzc/2ZgBRKg/FzfvrGhrY2DxK59uKxyUJoHRSJ14jGza9mdAzYUJcjuCcjTePH8bNsiQm31glF6kF8Azqs6YDV1GpyHMRaVgUVa+9799vhZsIxOArq8LrQH274vLnvISSgi9gWjbXJObc55q/BE00AAyA7NioGID6jA0qk+Miw=","nBu7mW1HmUCOsSiC6lqwZt9kQzHiwvqS7t6Wf7gblD+YZpS2ykCBYu2WziOsZNHSXoNscEINEUsPE5LkPF/qG4fY2UqyGB/WfKts/6ZZfuotICHFGqRwDTL7QVaGE7Id9UML9aZdx9mHVfIJGOelGTdsiWMG5VjFXM17VE2I/nA=","oiXJ7hdyR12L/BM4iYmPuiw95zccrOssAMm08BJWr9Jh8exy5eHnBwr6QWXqT8dYo27ia05wRhgkXxFw8ak+gZ+6cmJdspeG5ATXn/mKsZNcDucoOdj5x4Jrpuz3ErBR2aOQD3R3apc3O3U5Og6unozkjNXWmji1QTbPdivvGtQ=","XwZCRae9cUkxWPwTnREDq+Rha0FN7t1O/RO3reTZ9bXajy4CvDkdcwaygW3zflZk8WO8/WQfoE9xkUZl23/qJxxr1YV2TZdDTJnZSj6n+PP7KRmzZZUVqkI8CYqp9eh4dE3oHqTrtd3nJY52a5PI6QnM3q4sgVLJQZs80CKpDsc=","WxyA4+otmD2XjwnfYWBkaxTokk3xQZqCGeJ4I0eeISOqy6XXXaJYeZrpeC3t369DVWT8YnM54qA1e9QNn77li4Qgq82DIJBmr5q/rCd+s94SmIYeWZxWPu/q6rxkHYogl/1KoDUJ9BfpF96mSmY9WYTq6KZ6zCKtUb/Ylrjy7hI=","k5Ezr4BOy2/rx71LnW2FhhgMfqMLHfFA9Oim3OEYxrcaGFyxLnbFC8vcjRfwDoALTfUi0o6zO4lxkwLiXzB6YnXDyW1ClSuD6F/4JacgpZo3ABdQA2Arz3sZ0vhBDNEIlM4vaBMJuqquBu4Y9jhIv9xIldaYUTjrWJz4wMtu4tE=","bVk0qNU6PuN6TwZnGLtXUTS0mBOBxjcW9tO22mTfY092d14wiBuDHaz4PNbzW8fBK7coPUjmNtAyobQpkFCuaTOBZ4oFJ5ccNWJFLEhQk4VJYq6Rs1UhL+BQqiial68+2jwpDJuEFBbMBfMS8BTZpBwlodmXTnBI7bFViNdk0sg=","O//CV2ww2HXu3RNEZvOrVjJVu2gSOOrzPtkh26cmMgRpEf900cF2EEffj1AC5JZUVXS6NoaKrUhqvNa0eq65feLe6He1Lv1enzzFMvquxpqIO13dz1cjM70C4wxgcArRFzqlbdfFd6k8gOhXy4i1vuz+uUG9UnyeiapO+ojJwMY=","cHNNtzaqEvUgF31mD2a81hOgJcGk+eL4tyJ7HXhTLw3d5jz0S6tdPgA/wBqWgQd4MS4wtLVXXG18HXCpL01dDkOjS06CAYRGxxQFJZvLvxYs4gsqnXYdT/fJC82HivxiwIoh+5ndLZY172JQI4pe7fjOojWrsQz9O6vXmh91tqU=","UeAUeS5VWElo5G7+On4/BpJywCY55BaSMcByzNpaCcLBfxaHQLSwman4nYLOYCo7DvrivpP8P7rrYtWbxEQuLmhznDU3Xf1FH4hipeY0kjs0q294reTtemhuyeLGx3L0Kr3CP1fvA9YLjC2W44a3nwqFHZ+cGjFiAIKBMDUxN1k=","WjmnSy/lT0NiSXgEhzDNioER/kPQ1AzqV0k+yDVyidSzgce4WsCLI3AOh3LQCQpDwhFEyLXI7O3OiPYS5utlLsQfJxtz7vvCqZt7XFPbJRyuKpEbKb8j5d16IQnExIitYN3N0iPeuNnbbEKtyf9rbsvMH0m/u2wfT+4ofAIuRbw=","O0rlz6xURLgH6MZntvhtulFAHoYgZcBkSuPmoagBSiygrmJDFZAwAyb56t/U/DVQuIis6ZO4iZIixCVh6RcNZAD4ZoAxKNVwB25doZEQ8RBCe4OesGIVM26mdBdGBrMFbBsVYbnyr1h31mNHRqSeCmh+nI+jsBQnYEqRhvcrgWw=","m/is3p/3n3ZrasTp/JxETjBwKn0V7K0TAP19P8+ibTwmOOXMGgZ5tQcORO+6RCS2Zp++SGyWn0NU+U0KXzhCYGJc6m5I5ZUzEbu1OPjUyrO/Tjdd6ECC5SxOPL8svXOiHvLg54kUJXX6THd+szkw9qSl0+Uw35/C8o5IkqjnHwE=","P4U6RzJgPb32yFk6U6oLsQtfa0zaEd9Q5W/t6t4N9Hd3jceIEAONLDoW4MX1smMHdEsZURRVzELrB768xaSLgpTHdhEiNUpOXfknTDulZ5TiLJg+PETI3FZmHLYscnYW/8DCMLB55dD/H3YymZlgQebPHKC7vX+4ZFDg58/rLgw=","EDko4Z8h4jl9pLvhRmTvztokHZV+nuvfcVQtKnGTJgmJbbSfur2+4HHUs/3rnEn30on0iWe5gXX/t65ExwdV5czq7fKUtGZFHQEHErdAg8LwsJsF6adUF5lZ7eANZO9vOmyo3/Zde2O/tuWaemoPkjbEJkyhso/X3SKnwEifKLE=","VZy3TezmtyEdjf21cpTiKhtfJ/L/iQvY2kRpu/6PG0owosia0FWS4kdNC62OknQNaevPGuQzn8ysuFaK+eNR4m+ngBn3KjGdMlyka6mVuqCKhVGvUeHXTjr1gSFDsp+QoGbCCJhSX53NfUhftN/t+IAK+KLDJRCvcjh1Ap0vc0U=","dILSmHS6ugK3Bg6U/YuHQ9TOLmIT/MjG+k4xNz4ayb9Wln9OEyW2MYC4U/lqx5ARO69u/15PuSsWV9dkU3XAXaoBxh0Y+ymnR5zoFgXGeY9lqJxt8dIZi19D0AYnOxIxbofDv8mfEB+6OypDc+mA9w4ebkQ7GTH0bk3hlDMyJEM=","Fhlj31Yo0KStffR9RWYe4IoxNQbrg8W0KIaD7eOfxCDmDQjS6B2EDFg+56esf6w0grHzGsFXMw91D7NHkLbJFp5k84Yd5C6i23/tV+3Qmz2GlrW+Atj56a8VqqpxuSbmgt7VGt/M0RzxS0C0apq0PvT8w02WnWwzsvt+5D+5uMA=","F6Jpq7Av814O4JnclvL9OjthpcyBHDKWrT3W0ZJ6yVg/l0E2GONBz67N7NwMew5WD+oXFO1Ez2cK0ywhbxYBkYe5EoimQUebHd6G/02gZ9D+UtYqo2r/Mw6JQ10ihDHDC4uRlu9ZH0AC58s9iIlTi7jmTfMxY4fA9WlsB0Cdr4c=","k8tqdPIYr4PY2sixPg3Tfz8t0EDi7/GX6LT0dGWILEW8ZR/BaNzoA7AXiWrYqR/xlwljiLiPlHcAFFTqR0eAk1WWXUlK5lxHQAv3sI5al/WJgdFXi1yLRSlaAHl7SDbX4N3G1F5XNm74x3Ie9dS7VpQTey/NipJtyNLa7rF6Fww=","p4Al6Ml5Fb5yVD9oiUfzjKCkVKxF8ChLSkimQsDNmdS3Xb6KpHnbFc1s02OwM9jgxH6u/UXbzsBV44s3STzjlFKMy4kcPh8dAxyuQLgb1RNdXsj6TF+pakNsurIPNNNvKmOK8VcEocRlWfuVrF/ZYMfnF7PrEfCFHn+gRSrPFsA=","HSvma4T4c6M9bhCXGtu6N3tKNwD9G4SuCHm3l0J6phup5utFKqFMVXc50dfcRJPIvfpgbvuMNI9wV+8tD6V/SmKT+s85ynUhr2/nVY+Q2raMjbn+VXJsefQOlyWLUAgB4DzOOqjdTtJrN90Isk0nCd2O9cAk2X4bBkP8JumszyA=","PoC+tajeijH20hk1WIroEsHH+rDYIUZmMXuqt2moX2rHJyOZhZWtCapud11GzwRK3cGSBQEmSnEtoCJO+LPRKYOi5qtAh1q6Kjrnj65TdXYlqYwmv4NpDi3NBGA0q/j6ibnswp5BcSoGhD7fSRc2vcaM4cBY2ygmN2hAcazIpeU=","e07WqMiu7Jvo/fX/r7z2HgqqU0twF63Cwze8zqfbpq1F3C9X4JyhPxJb6rhUoV8Wuvlbl8a8JlVqHnV4O82pUrMzTykgSFqgwvIXgA4QP8wtPhyZiDsm0cQOXt4kSiga47xJs40WiF79qg3h8AFLXyE+MdBUULkHzb2g3gyeYEM=","NOu/JVCSRYal1Hw2vpzWKUooDcxiz8pQqOpaDQVgjWTz0qkPWnELJuJ6CS4vUO525OhEIdy2P/VKV8aqhMoP3UAQkVPFFnjhcFgX+hpgWDWVfSz+rrrLYn9Dbu4BMA0Cldulv1Sd92FX0BbFomKWO+TmilQjE4HcqicsWc6uc5s=","R1jbDGZ06k2tdqwfYbW8LCfA5b5RYwKmROsthpEOmskPqDVqHmoT/lxnI0E4FpOpIWTXbQCsAO7JYuzNlnJ6ck80+auWrGzpqrlbauThyzvAZ/X45pc3YT3YwmlqFLDvSYXpUAiMYWExPTWYqCJthApqjzQ/UB47s7x6+D5BWrU=","jqBBt+ngGVsj0inDUgQSQ1P3TgyUNLQMdpSQ2mzcAwghzjJGs3w1FsxUfdL8sZ5De2FPLv03YfOShO0bG8N7qHQngnvDp16qiEms+a5V4MiyiAl8gHFfqP5K/AZhyiEr4SzIsO0l0qQiQeyHNY9onfNLRTH1p85aVMN0Xugxk4o=","dxlgTUdy0EfLWjW0TcyKLfocrc4m7aKEXblep9bzsQ/AmayLbxGiTixin6/WifeHPwXMzDVYHvEaN572GGRt6HRb3IkJc4urPHTIe1pgx88fXU8Ku+MMIixn9FvKkZniiQPnDmMiu0J/PtueFXd7lxDE+/yeK36K6ezhgGBjIWI=","AKqu94tL/qEDdEJY7tz6NuwFYSsvwNGTJ7vgGSOWQ3YKWjR2bIWzBcmekZglkP2laBZwWxLZrdCLuaY0aMolN20mV+TqdKEg86tNQ3HKX2CyZZOAMT9VSi/eHOTL8dczQh9DCIydJyXysxBctD54z/RoL2eAKu6Wx4fEoTCuiCE=","X+VpgInlMxzNqQm1A9RTCqwJgF2TaBqoW8hGnVz7pvjF5esmI7hdpWDzvFre58uKc5I2n/WmkWYYwRwTZP7RMUtG8tE1dUjC2ozTOjGuLrFab6Wik/FwcsIXoRE0gFt8oSg6/0B37xEv/TndZxE0G22b0GRQWD5YN6KTFJ6e5U0=","d5q1xGtrJtBbP/Rn9zMcCj5LG4jWd1CoWEpiIqBkyy4jbicOCcPolssZId8yaXYB2v4g8m+q0lcz0JrwS5qdABLLg/gQfkgYSagYEpQhw0PEGp3tDYh+Py1WW9Id/ZbGvAGuyc1+y/vykvW8aT06BrrWjOvdyb94Xtsl02Ak6Es=","PzRgvVjL8JciNA8Ev78ZxkFaVTpT1rQpPOnTO6p49pY7zTymAXOuPGEGjUgeTCVmOp7cRNW0+J5eRnt9AV2xdURMfkxXaC31L4esO4n+oGCIJ5kmnI4UoZbVI6JJamb3OhiupEcXMZaGaCvAACVsLiQ3Hx6cz6i3XMywYdH+syk=","TO9WBtE3Mh0Kk/YRbfXvVNJiecTRVIkCfC1vqvyRymRgLd5UZxiJwsO3VQ7lZccpesprGPUAHRg+biRwrpksZ8f/oeFqZAt8jZsutJj+bDkQkZvi7pgvy9uuaJ8VB/LHM0+P1vQQn0HIffjdXxIqce3xTO5fIibV9diLVb66+xA=","gpHf2CvGc2lRB8nObYYYH/gdV/pHMu5SpKew2LsVw49lwBrryRJkImK29EKrH90ar8ZOparzY0p4BSHjhjqzHhGfLfjg6Wyhq3OfAmdT1mOktz1FtMkbLTE3jutz1oE5pS3fUmH4wSA1nMz/dKboVUQHazsJHDf/L6aNH5xljyo=","WhgufHL7CNPftNtH5yCNDwtKpVf0fazGv4KY5M7WffTdkaVVfDX4JsSxyNFBPOYP0YqII7qwkSwZiQIjzbsJ1/CWv7B6lSEqDOH9qt3OGx5DWFsMK/I2BqZmaboSdzTK2SGrzy5n6fMWGJv3vUgBNsH71MigSoUfdM+o73GNqSw=","eZNBdVL3EK8sqBRuCVUDq7yIaNqNvcv0hqfweEolia0cAXLs0ZzJzfT3gpcek6y1m+O4sRNRGW4CkIF0yZE9aVe894cL7Wm66y+TX7EpmMd3c6Dg0s4/e0oq2fFWs9V/Z+kWmO33LY0Z9nlJoY9peMutN2ChYlkdwSDllAIJN+o=","TU7K+ORHQE77TKw6HQfPXRrn1/4fVJc7Jytl/+/hcB9uguvOjkP+jnGjz0dENKtZid9ow6Sp5EMfkOW7Cz9mmdvYgbISAM/IobwugMvVwz6ohynmenxYY9571UC9yjY56BhWjRidxAMavF/5Iilv5FiuZRP1u6CLzihkl8Sjmf0=","S4iqDR9x9MvNThJth73ZWlaCej3HIXkIfN4IMV9gOYbCc3e2WFOcv9zB5hRh8iEDLqOIe0zRmSV/lmRBdp5BuHUPYdpzkVPZHuC1MD3stKLcLtL6HEyAV4izeDi7iOJCddDX0EIPxwJHJhpEFV4gX7Qx7UBLmf7/ruQLHts6B1E=","QHi+H59vxGX65F8q9ZB8LFIT+1MXQW/pDoRRoWa9y6K7Xbk1+bI8cqa8FRC+vwO4zSlZd3PMMC+EgdJzj1S+mqpNmo2APJ7lxwxHn3Vs2Vw2/i+qOLdOwxlcATmp0WTsMBZ5C2gDPFkx1VqGfUMaHZOxjjf0O5hYpKkD4v0jSJs=","A9mAf8HtpsOrIFvLM8mjYEAWLgGXtn3nnxGB3MkFOqMBEwou0o85wMWhAORCyd8EkI0otEM8iRc4j+QVYxKXs/p4FMJOfblRo3/Z5ppKOBWXSNsKS7PZm/gjyFmQpOzDlKGhoKch0PzzQ5O45uff2rbNQg9sSyM58AmCz780Eaw=","F/ETESVxG0eLZa36c70nlYYtPwb3j3980zAExAuT50jzUR6JpjkKSqk3yI6rtf3+mlpEVNzVYL49hwV2Jo02bwhr7Cmc/zS/V7v8qtmj+NA1ALpDNGiqjFW9Kj5UmnO2IKq3swg426nlIQt8W22djkW3/DQ5bJCl/WX3HLyRqVk=","qTpQK5CrGWBuJ9fhVXaNg+ujF02eMUmuakWB5U6HN9YdEyj5/VqaFUZbeojPY0asfgfvPm3gPQJYn/FXoSHxQM5vTSVvx/cZ8/TiQgLeZ+eB/09UMTqUSPDNE+R+D98VC/VomMLIQJebw9WVa83kVTEcYHKt44VmssmHEubSOOw=","YzH4OB4r76S/YFPp8VN0cUNTwb75ww5NESVDWFWl4EYWRfWKNH/CJX4SVi4fqhiRyjuwO/38LnAd5GWqTYxo37I1oESixQQLUeBYl8jtyUjBu2HYg6zy8RRAuwwgKVsD3gcbenHI2PwHp0zkOOEOivJqZ4SckudGlfQl2Q1hTEs=","E/bjX7PLBBkzb5SBz+EMDLNGcVM2+nUXM8Yqrwpax8nIStbhrfQWMmwAOQUG5kcC4jSlbrqezr3F3zcqeXs9sx5jA045/GsiL4oCE6ksImZhexdueeqEGO0+ZVHZhVUkRbdR50p+dbDDGf5ta3ZrtnfXqRCua4lQowtu42p8g3s=","nFzwyGZI2rSEL8iRj+RkVdKMGQEQq4In3ICTOk/Iop7dCC6oocHz82p+Fgm/EOYYAoL/SHQOzegBqIVAKz1Bx0I+Wf9qMXhfkXMTNKKHzWoClJ3PWLR28+cW/2oPQJDq5D32OmBvR02V7rgd72P1XRUCkp41vn0R1tl9px1Rmow=","deFVExlJA/nu9tm5jexmlbwoL0w/DBswGXPA4EeH+kUlPwhm+kp9v8twfWH5/l7DpExwMKtamKHh7R08xeni2LyzbShuiGtrC5Ocqy1WgXYM5STSMiNbRHf9JfY04Y0chZLxc3r5U6DL2JgM0cjT57tYof1Vqi5zKzk9KwBR2w0=","UEthrGKi8xwfpLLoyvlF4gvd1g0LzbskZ4vDH62BRCGEXD4LKjwzoZFlSmggoCA3gCW3FOA6nIvR2U3RnAdDuUDmmiLkOmFbO2jX2hQXlxy2raJIr3V2LqkQODhKDfl93bNXC3kScFbMdV+m85kt+ojnIiaXJgifuU0tnwsaPWE=","GlU82nmfWxxyLRkGJalpAdZduaEBcnOYRX/yYJ+FdEIERk7zUynx9/b5Gor+1K5wPL18JUoix810fTrR7p0mbCIz1ULo6i/xvLRuzZSmmiaHqd88ndIZfRcoCyaVbSwsUBoGqsdFT4DrlfMblXINLnrPReTzi8rfw23AqxcsJyo=","Sa9YB1hCAa7U6CKWrE06Aq3pmyhhumE+slQigol8GlTlhZLkSDW1+ouo13a7oM5muWm5XTXHobUqp6NLiUlskssMaj+fZw/DhS7Zg4x21nMKHapRvKznHYxDd97WWxXjj8R5begHclwzKocsDOt0Q4tkeNaciGwMeJqsydleLpk=","CyUljtJTNpvdDC+8dKZrRpty8ghjzTEf63BRk/Wy22fdhWbh4/hFWe72DjUkAJlSlXKa1YjmNfywmsSvsVBrUnHfGsiHwpVc41rsHTtS65TKzCXlQbMHf3mxoH7AUdpIfWM6Mj3VVJ45K0VjU5sRHG3s/zc4/TfwPxXFYaZAzog=","fwFVoIiOw0zPcKV2SY0azNDgAem9cVPGtBqVHOTpoeraF3+UvfbIfz1q+k04HiCu4EhzRxAWej/qO1bdOhqhrlrM1XLhie4UIWuOvvPU9YhEl10vC1mwxJHcxafV+sV2ecKJgm6eL4Cr75WDCXy9mis3AXNyE8VvcKGI5/VjlDg=","pLX6+eMgTN8Dki0VeQeNeCMt+WdWcFqvJmsRaQIZs9gWqPEexYKZAR37w/Q4J0Fy2xhiIdrYAmKy+rr+QWGxRJD5Bm7ncosy54dMSIRw+2U4jKvWCGNJT+7qoSAjJxI7dEVrMnfJwnF+E5RXlwDDHpsoFrfKlEa2kyWg8N+/bXY=","DX6ovXoKM6yeN7L9VW2eCEzX8hrmhYBl6rW8Fk7HV5/YiLYixgfPeqSVKqlwr4USPprnxt6zPeO7VzdEjX/1JtSnzBmCXAFK4YgTupK7hnG3q8lPlNx1Qg1Jjnkn+UtXD8kikDbd2KXN6Ms7xrgvwle8BJ+CtbkeZ1l6W+QF6gg=","a/UJOceOWKLT+W7i5zxLnEFjnFHUoCAVZ/1YGRYPks9yyucRskxN4ny3PrmpPTO7QgnkrxLkRKRhSJmVMpYcVB4LKLVeIe7HBjDGGPZGoQBzuYDPInLcKELcBPEouyiVYF/hdpBbp7XuZngre4W8KPBtT3qHAnUQRowT5xe8Is4=","ZtjH15IvdAImUfb4QC97D6KhAoCWzuVC5gAIq1LYVNIX+hAdKpxPsRR2/4KAH4Av7Wv/MM8TMAnWDvB67USoneOxm2BYYiibDh26ld7Reu3WEohpymKszxEc0Tc6tOk+XbU7TvU5xQg/6r1ylKZ7lNM9kYabusLqWTLOq4GMM2I=","NQtKhJ3dQaGdaq8Fd6UzExBU84SXIhbT+wGr1PJ5Vs1miQ80J0TgYaYmshYoQlQkvy5hLb1YZdYsp82h/xq3vHPc0Mc9uWQ+172ZpC5AbTePR0rIMs2TZHhR6lDEQp0Cyc1RfEl4RVimOir6yJnfmGKEDYBAQ1Jo2VsRLX4ctCU=","ApyXHMvfDe4Jrh7DXMnMviAZ/xiDEicCT9gtayi3l46CGY5+BXywA0oYtCiSb3dtRJtGyCxN0x7GCLQMkSkO3MpPGDRo+J3/Z8mT5gKczKzdOe/2jtOyrru09FWpVrTjT9m8L34nN+plm3acdmU9pdxZbqXXLP3JDvCBwDd3gi0=","qkCPogYiEkHVP4wM2aTtyb5tcP9gLhdo0zHmHeiBAV8dT/8Mq76XefGVdx2J5EQeMgz6uXPgvK26Qs0xz1Kpz6S4S8wbyiHQuLex5zgNG1+vnqng1JKQMNAj6xdZ/eWdoEEn/IvaxF1FtsbTdgQpGq2ECLbytmn9ADsp+LCzGeY=","b/ZeK8BE24gKjr+Sv4G0v6PBxuJRMD+ljqb2frtY0iwKhVsKdmM7A+LnXF77Q9v/+eBaBJzelxGrsIWzXFIyxjAo99Z4eSLx/K4fSbTfmtb6onQaV/ZVO8IDArcpnIvLE1jwRqZqSgpyD8XmrdAflNm3tHkIg0DOlG20PZDlG4M=","phycwObkFgoiHkvSSzauIHO9ZMU5A0dlm95pzGOAzC02LC4C774tbBD4EfYTKci6VP+kVZioi4dqMcICGrNqK8QOcl5OPyMTOFrPlwxXVvGABnBxrKpy1sJQOD/Iye2lX/0Z1P46Vz0zQrNCcUNaXADGdTHab+U4qsVp7ZyypHE=","ds/mkGSmqjM7d+tZNjgpPmJSt54i5sN0g4NfjAdEf/iNhdXLleyIeyNyvvR3Mf9lDdRhYLXm/spqCH0RdCk2sb53q98KxVSM25rwMejszb1HeFjP6EywxycvcrQmW0T0ucmyAqxqVRWdHSPyg96eEfdDgKkuY+Mnt1VywgaiU+c=","pXuReNx4h/0TQC8BF3B0k8ru18mSfvatUf00OP36piKNhZNPkW685dc7YXFgPzvkyie7CVHcjDsjfY3Ecbcxrsx6HtN8rCwo+NczWBTWNzsod3Bv6ypPoHNxVJLC+Md5FLjet3qd6BQrE1kRe7FDUKsiFIBy2jFmkxhaq3VQn4E=","M188lD4GVbW22azNESkw3Ae/MX1QEDpBs9Eus/dHasxmIeTEh++ICEkjpIXGP30DBRokrWOdSA7yX/eSJOsdLGN4zFhI8fowonAIEIfM+EDrMShAhz7KEAwPFaFh04xj94mDvFniFTDqFjia2Ni2TyabSynDc0wFAKbbAVY/Kp8=","jsAOp30/z4ibLJWEJeVDJCgUSGMf6oIhhgppzChk/aKNn7w+MkflWml+xPUXjFYwOXh85xkhKR/CzulZitB3x+pr1IQo6XCZ/dgXPah9PbOicwEiBqKotTmEbcogYZNjcCUWl3uKgxb++4VsUQHLbWYdP0LrmLG6OksKZoZ/9bU=","Pcxn2k6kLQZPAd5uvrmZ7n2GollvMbWR2FeS77Hi/U4kYWOIxhtM1O4XHe5J5NNIpwluYqwfCgPgR3Ggnd3iwKJqSIG9Eco34kaZhoZUMSL/I3j2ORJr9l3tld87q4pUKpE4FYsOSX7pY5a5tjZ11z57oIf9tQu9FERcltYXZ6U=","JUsfP/ZqZ/LitkkFpKCT9iVJlxZ4CzMZLPwmnquku81ZRRprQeX6s6hXy8zZpmJVnsPZhRFzpgdCInmsCyjWYFHBdL/M2zqXelCwSOESuGPI5J5AsIAgHm3a0AwBSLE9lSuJPoXUV16AYeXx69LUGCTz9etD6sZTadG3EE87Sdg=","mMjHDFvAdXQyRhgQOHNyMTnpPY3JE1O9mH+U5ciAtOmSYAqz2930Pae53doh3TKY3tC6N1MT0ETmDZtHunlnMVI/bBm17IhyhIZAthoIlS+4i53e2aToyJ1vNgivCI4ufEbyQzZ9ytK+MpwnmYE6dMwxnohlw+W+thQs917ZirY=","dHKxaWtDyisj9zFUOaQeQM/YbUJI+HBAiskL6zsn1Ysn1ONKMmGfbn6SYMAuMvt4JrR73+fAluh48wwQvChYi2HiG4qnLW7tXbvyhhiT8MiChrq0IKUJhkMHKMqJGB4VbPrczHzM8jjR5jEyaCH8onfcyyb2RmpmLhf5vlVgPEY=","ij6RqDOu8Gn9hBxFoPtCns6/onG0NatWu0Jg0PDCxVF2zMSSxphD2o7pw+6JnuBmat8nwL6sD/XSm8/3+NH30PHejnGNloRjw97jCwVjuMoy4ICJR2GIaoUdyrzqq580g+BUWNAlUuurIVnjZrR5w2llmp5pP91eNHL/sUTSGvY=","bVTIQEfyAqEffE/4qDi13LsR3doQkdI0BZSRze+DSOm2WsgnySgIy8uugobbCOncvQSgPjerP6vwHzphJLc0TwnNlEDa0LA1RRUCEJY10U9oUplglOdPk5qdKWCgQy4rgeDOLfCLrHmnzb+PJpePXk0FxKdOn7zoPPsbElruU8Y=","pcaNIAbg9i+GAuGxMeHSJ4IfNeG6J4OrbOQP8+6c+zcevl3Gas3ofFdxWiUmx7nfSyI5QMP2Hfk+QXv+bvZKIi8ouxm8LBg9vOAxSiUhUlX8WSO/8m+7AQ1GdpqIl7lSc3fkb1r9byWTvLyW8RFJUrMx8RHARtmZ0y6LxMsuSaA=","IEVFnTLTc8Z/9XXyjPQTTKOgjShjvNSFK0q32dwmPZv/N/KCC7YzlWofAqQ0/nWFSQmaSZtZFM/QqiRAAk3xHQSNRQ09fM0llqdjHqA4EKKlJGkMLQ4ErD0FLrV3Awebn0IMLSFSW7ei+Vz8xOZJGTDctlKcmKqg+0YKE6EI5n8=","axajgNjWeZ9cZjJq4NKhkLb+nicTwNFOM3t2WHufe69Wh0MvC4K3s2jUzoL+qlXhMx0ZpKFg5bj9FfVg7KgUJuaFtVGvYJmaj5aMB6S/3DtWitb6n7IuhlK7fD3AgxUiVvmTY64b7L5/xPOTrCKuSMhG5XwYfGptystXxTSYqfc=","EDQpGb+i0+ENcXIlFvPgCb7/ayUv41SJmQmaXUkWj20pXQvg57Z3k1jh8smm9GbL8WL0YmGexg4d66ojEKHfPd0QK42AptutPYQQg3FkDL+MtFDdNg/9cG7xwXTIKt44XB6Kjla7M6oqAUlfmnHnaIsxUsFq20qDZdR/4NcnxnQ=","UuQZt/YHAepGMgkdWg8RYqWHfzrejB1M8im1Nl8OX8IZ3DCd76RgrE2Qa9atH8e0XwJxvXC1ZjpqgbGOh1IFnBgxKjgWYF+eWd4sG8vlk4LbkVs/AMoZV4azru2ek3zYeqM5b2LQGup0r7HCx9pUYDCB+uyEkKa2aed3kzYoIlI=","WGPa3yO6qAgrAsAorqswncwjixZsOvLzoHRkOT4Jgd+V0XdXyXskOQNYH74v35C/tXGCyXgRik3Er23+K3/NrkWOjSTxXJ4rIwAfLQyFvx9NigskeznJez2+aQjQXnGMubeG7PAwMzn00chGcTLy61xLQw2UYvvaXvsBsxqA7T8=","nHG0mcuOPT75QDJ54kF6HuXsdJOXAoz7K+ioI0F7oUQyTFY13n8f6b4VarUEHkl706LP51jgEy/RnYpCqAFK4iDU6Ama6lhJLWWikOvPC+3CAr0O4dcGfyqFxZICicgzuN4b+Y7tJLystHZDwMcBqq78NadXUIRnDayPL5d0Log=","mvFsu1KRGfYDmJBMb4lq4T+3VGkzYaHPIVCzy7f19aYsFs7aVmeM2hxjNHg0ERzoqrsnZfHcoP9PMkIYw5lR/oSkistwCrWyVbgO85CKOFxh4gSlP3zfg5iJzEHXRThxfK70y/txtSI5JxIdnHNbdWo48kr4JyFYDJw7mrTvmUM=","DAsvdeFDCiyGFSSeqyfCD0d3KvLjnbOTXZcZsyuvh/M0T+qaISrIQljlZy3Gvs98X8rnEBmuFunaGCOMr8EJ4HtkS5MF/XsZMtCoQtRk4Y7AnwuS+8IZ0aT3mBzgQAbu9SccgODDxIvltOO34FXPb2kli8PsNM9LPJAf7cTb2NA=","MpC/80NSahcHATkKzAxJ1SCYROnqsmVOWXRvzWnSTsA8l1Q10HX7JlVUeXrjAQghp7iL2rcG3R2oUzcb4H8VsabTU1oiqi/tz0QkAxc37eYV1Oh05F/+/pasJiTmnPeTTli8Ub4cIijq9dz4RVGG5d6qQy1ILXF8PxDEJkOZ1YI=","NBswb71WYSuaFGmPJO+5Wx1VNKaOJLQZX326ANWZhUOV7Jrxjus03WOPp8d0UN5az3aimWdMP7PIWHZSZMCK4KkmYlqgKF24FXvv0K7YteUGenp42g5KbqBEAgV19Dzc8WeddX5Bc7ml7nlKyhlGIu0PqEnYKqEuXYf9qmxLGpg=","GPcjIoJsgr3yoAx2f17TtIT8ugskdWMCJV8N9I9Z94wMuY9WRkaUDABWB1FGoNxESMWcF49uYiiOEmvYFVghs4//zRgROA4ENvru/hxqVOgoaN5Pum95IGhDaoJMKPwGbJAaCdbuY5+cG5vupCR3SonVMKvjsfsi7CASxYLFF/g=","HKnU/Hz0zgrNz2Y/F/5WnLS8R2MFPEcM35uLSMYsjrA4Baw+gSNGw3iSxaEKRKfFJZrrSEVQzAGhxYVbXblJh2sE7YliOdSAyZ2j2o0kC6BmmmJkGibqi82OYyzKyRErzh8xzRuR5rdkzHCdSPbjkdhAmJuYjHCkQ1AkwrCm8J8=","F9EWp9e5qakVwcqfkveOSrizA3VvXqSpIAx6qgEkd4FONU6lH9NxgOh/IZXFpT2sNAUES4lkum6FBdRQEAgPg+fIBIucyx83uT2Cw7C6sJlpLbbfdM9kweWrYblv3WRFK+E5IiOMZtBhwEaQBS8ZNMrv64VbIHQZ9UXrSH4z/gU=","IP7rUlh6CP+GHyl9J/zp9OX0ZxTZYloM4kZ7UpnSqGgkEdNFDV5zHPjLfg7FyqtjTYdbigWJwUB1KqyZkBgQgkzbw/z0VF9BuGoKJR0Lz6CncUGcFrA/JyqGasyYISaMGywhB7l70wvo2ulUoDxFMVSq6L6UXVvOWl+r8Q6x9/E=","UCZqRhlw4sDoRQ9a6RW05ejpuQlBEFqivjHBCUGWKFJe4GB5EE/cUz0y777pNrvSggF4KksO+OIjmZpi95GiS5uOkQTn9h3Z6XGD9VE6yo/uWHlVVdzd08TmSwQGRqM+NxLFjblmgd6WCrtXLybm3pb4AuDFqu3TgEt/NoZ5SQ0=","Byc+2qLxaZujf3moVYnVwjRjkssxE2PSl8Mrz24EwD4cBuQnatFsnNvzoXUXgc15ioYRJWgGpYIUdJRXZoswAIUISZZ1AKhKx08jLoI3bFdJYtAfxWbTU7LZtcu6uiS45bTiuDKVxlIbTodbsxnPYCMq6kfVX7yiv2EgY0cPTHk=","aVs8i40CGtnyKzmSvhMhVBWgVt1h2sCL/+urupYKvlFk03clCdmFa9zGd9ZP3mxdo1vhAKGGoyR85+oKV9O9L7lPAFlSFNWUNYtIXZ1tOqKVRn+9/ti7oO2yLGGrL5MD/XBO0sIPbVU8M/3PPM7KS6vTz4rFKixbo+Qgcv0ulGE=","FsVg6FpLMc8mdUhqWWBbtRLUnOZuZowJD73VP+3yvN8PVFUOTndULvIm1otrpowXqMXdGEozcEt8xHo444NV98wZfSws+mXexPW718nLg1oBP9gx5YYzIuPXdi54Gc9PYlPkdkp9TJrSFkoyD3xG4r3WXBf2CfM3vV0RyOrOE2w=","BciCcIVwVHkuxY/Q1XZ9thFvwephi7wxInX1slzJjb0MaKlS1+kOSwab3eqkGpxQSdzxpn0t1zprRuVMXmuZ1aw7dKo2zdFH5pF5P235skCV2u3dlt8qK0xYgj6NOWZgqtse+QlFtFcyzZQFSMmbNTM2oGIonR81/cFL4rVc7dg=","QadoMq8sc1wl1tm1IffyIXuzvWizaloZ5XsKybqHP5ItZGLtIsVTP4BNIgVedgfxQTiPmrENe3ExyPeZia8wqblYvLXqUfm5K02xrL15I6jp7ZftNzmhTJqMY8WgHrT/9SmZpPPa1sEGQiVXE5c3EHndppVoIkgAmqf9Ar2Y4ck=","WMtmRXS19GuLmwTlUsdhSFbYRFiqGsA/fDGUR1pQpk1kiFAMcjuJZqb5Swv4vhfoLSpsqdLf+c4MhsKRDGHfDrywV66XVF3ju+tHmv5BoKTx6tMV0+4jsDydRq9qhpGw6oYv+arV7pu43ma9wZu4hO7zNrOBFL07TD6IOO0Jzy0=","B5wDsciclfHpDOwo4l2BNL6KIYoHyvzip/rBgE7EDQdIsYJANlcl461+SqE+faF/QJHuwKh5jyxxzFVGGlDGxJMbO2fnsNH07fF+pw+3rhFkGC6Js2MfULdTNZld7JSakL7VKSIO65ze/tHq1hUtjuGDmopRXDJsf8tKo424vHI=","WHYCopiWkqkYzExrnTovtfmQdV/SLgnpGHZlVCVb3tSboIssteS3jkNGIfylJjN5N4+7HiFFu40xEDORwPnOvskROrLNbk4Obfb94SXxYAOxS2F3HuHv8GimnIeeTZfjeYF+qAG+r30tM2YetiBMIRTuCX8scHhrY9mlA4w6xgM=","AK8YzdYxlGdytVT8P2Ui/VUSGnyYOeBcboIOG7IzfllWJfs21dfpscUGvMrUiKqZS7i6WlXHUSYudlaeZq7cCm3xqkcf4vfwoz6At7RCmiIhWqnqkjjJJhxjIyVIJbrFT7P5VEkK9YrJ3eS9S+5bCjTeUVaWyQxuWjbw2o5gy/8=","mL/cOyxDFRLspoLmF4mmVpy8jHWt8I6uyNaEhcVN5mPeyb85ABbxw/JVjle2dwUhF4Pa+sWplZeIMh76JyUnDxro8TtIgG9WEhrHGOtlY+Hll/dR3WMhCRKYyz9SdGJTgsZYG3H+clos/cjV2T509Zfr+HRdSEZxEeXiL+yCX6U=","BDApLXXwSVSApjCF7T6LjP6R2TAc9QrxGVtS8y0baW+GxfEmCfr/BTDI9IHy2ON0GN6xeJvhRSMe6K8mWcJ6yyf2AlNgEnKyHlccrhBAFJ53QsHM0rcvAkYqVPiFPVXeZcraR8wTx99eCMEBZwTELFp6rnXKuYU09pN+KW9L7xg=","TR1tz36rJrtUYUFOqK7A9Cnk4w7HiuvqDKyrUX8i4jkKNYFsLcfaOgBJApBSEjJGoCiew/WjI3x5vgAG+CTx+LTiRWcluTy21aQXdDEjgiyBYJs5ykbfeomXkcCWNENWVtLU0H/ccgTmBFknYwbfUu4K8ZEJZzQy0Ofy/Z+fOtY=","RX7eAauCqgeVjHpS5buZiTnBVZHgBmxkxqmkbKDbJEgfwl+0On0jBVIQNDwYW/JoR2y8xwbHFToGZ4sP+k1vY6bXCeT7IGgv+GbJaS3VlrD7plk/JzeWTdd9Hu7ApkPp4S43jTKwBrwvUD/2gzOYXoWDt8hpvyCLPWpA1rh5+3c=","cGp6i+siSybph+hRaOcjctCGbH0bCVlkHjej2mHZMPutTBiNueOUeOw5jCm7w9ngc84BBl/90JlA/9U0mTSh8K7yhgi8dgHWK5pDo+BesPiv5r0Ga4hT9+OYIV7wX8yhiDc8izeyR51/m5Sqvwl/KEUm1+wqOa+jh4FwfMoQnms=","MCMmu0NtDQ112SPMOt2RPirgiflHTjTpwVWGPn+uihp6HTvozzB57OsrWR0sVDf2mUfukkiJqE9KmVsx9Uujby5ekCLfCw7GICEn6m3yJDTW2Nrv/sBDtG1J04JOGAFL32+ZU4DYT1XvNqwVY9UXzzlqNHkadO28Es86RrGvSzU=","SzJmkf3exPTbEk6lmOkHiIY/l95h09MFMAjZesEFUbX9LgWAaYMdFn6c8dH+JgDhmu2a+W2EKtIv64/N7t52RabOQVAA/0iGI6LPevhPjiBWD2D5/AoM+xF0Cl+uBrpHCEhoMK5MK28HVgl9EXDaT4KtELeC48TUJI3WivmEhtA=","fD1TDxNGjDhwQRM1pWb9Xmtd0agPE0n5V8+it+qSyqutLDtZ98GsTSXZSjhgA2+x059+MEm0d6r/TKZL2br4iD4JRG22cQfls55zxFiwBi6HfB4Iyc5Mkt6ffwp96A7eEK/da4II4MqPzYf9lold3bW8/8fMTtNF9CwViiSZiiY=","IvJ/9aKWsUrjmxtCtRoaGMTWM1K80Yz8Suxm6wb8MfBqDUG2Hr+MhmTLsKzfAWtHQJgyx9CixOrrxxuvORZDikCOq8Cl+JIjEM+K0V7SUpNbdVIs8pr1Opapc8ro9BHy8+bseMRrUjig92psVxQVK62srjPNrk11PT2XzRtwKYA=","cuASUt2Uc+DqavAMvPnSu3ANPPAzZ6EAximqtWWSbCHj3kX+9gTMLaDMRPsHh3RpoB3SfqFkZLebJoS2OTskIcafCDpadfVGFOENcvlImnBNnBifPZApVi0JdJQA1DFyQQREVBNAwJud4jyB+Mm7T5HMMsyuwF9xRSXIaNHvO1s=","ehhMS+vXJ0PMUVwOprXHmLI7QUz41COBvYMTv0hLvZjsJQx4gSEyLKxalC28ofDvne0/X2DTI4VJAXlhsbTN02ab6KRsfixlsHhl0H9ljM6t/0M+F+4DYAidij6itTpxzEhHQ6em6zTnbJn0H6hHUQhF6gSHgzoCW1bhqrzm7vY=","QEQEpfd18cU+ZakCU9LPsf8GWeg6EllwD12qJEb5SY2fUWzlRC1TmEkaddi0AX/0xRccY14FOuVB6HrqpeAJv2wR32dr1Y9qstwdhrF6P08oSMTL6DDoCiKyOHlnPUb1N5b7/80i96Ebnujtdpa5jMZ3P0NhQFntlaSb497eSIw=","YX0eXLpzR7tSlMjBkdoYzyqWwZ3ojzCS70B9U5cUkTaxLqtwo2jB95nU42aHXToRZrHZvD4k5Oi6RCQRVwM5htoclLa/eCe0tm6McdLbhGbFjywteJ2B6As08TtxRiRcNHCIv0TkyKEeCQOMceU/lNyVrUSQfL32FOHT5LybIkM=","StnkaydVgI0r+mMsUXbBposg5mKu0ysEk2kcnIjaeCH8BBKWcIwysRC53upITmcze+qNCjtg7MXQjguftTbpdBM/hFRPjJ6p058AZNBxtzqDi3jZ01bIk4qkMV7ZcT0kDvmjJd4EoYyLzdM9sb5vtC7zmX7A8OuJyQREZKyJpS8=","XROjq92iUff91yFqYvmA1evnr1vq+E7CUWil4aWrMvAKr5zipYW8BTRoWgCmbYbFqOQt9lcVkI4EIOGSWVhWW6frRcFrn6ZDdyPtepn67KLynr8+C2leDAnb4MiGij/OarDGvLnDQPXDJSgbK993T16Et4tPGcF2li4cRjLMXq4=","NrHgOCjQJQenerVkBXLEjomju5j9ljPQl8KT14x6qK8wSCWk3jCZnXc0E7Tvv0cfu126EOIqxGWE/wlucllI9w0V+BiPE6DJu+s/moMaUow+4Jmp1FHbrFS2Qmbv2RsZ3yQEVwly0Bgtc8ayIerymTAJJJ77D/LleLAdhtOnoBA="]);

                                log = function () { console.log(arguments); };

                                function fib(n) {
                                    return n;
                                };

                                r.map(decrypt.decrypt).then(log);


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't encrypt arbitrarily long data with RSA. RSA is only able to encrypt long data in chunks, but RSA is not [meant](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14/13022) to be used as a block cipher. Instead, the data is encrypted with AES with a freshly generated key. The key is in turn encrypted with RSA, because it is short. This so-called [Hybrid Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is faster and more secure (if you use an randomized and [authenticated block cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Authenticated_encryption)).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks that worked perfectly. We tried doing the same as you mentioned and there is hardly any delay now. Thanks

Comment: Please think about whether you need that at all. If you do any kind of cryptography in the browser, then your site *must* be delivered through HTTPS. If your site is delivered through HTTPS, you might not need to do any cryptography in your browser yourself. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: You can post your own answer with the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for us as suggested by Artjom B.

We have used AES and RSA encryption here.

```
<script>
    function load_image()
    {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var img = document.getElementById("image");
        var url = "url";
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);

        xhr.responseType = '';

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("john:secret"));

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            var test = JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.response);



            var response = test.m_Item1;

            response = response.replace('"','').replace('"','');


            var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();

            decrypt.setPrivateKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+
                                'MIICXAIBAAKBgQCsqVGJUP6PhkjLSk3BkVRxg9ikUMZjN1BLS+HmEcjlVbkbsSuO\n'+
                                'K9uMmtZ7rkmL5aXcLxzNS1fexlr/ixvHeaK43KDXxob5drxcwCaRpadm4JjEKWiG\n'+
                                'ExbRUIorzFRqxCKFTwXRLerXhyFrfTqv/XNA2F94XwWBNuE8cs9S0ude9QIDAQAB\n'+
                                'AoGAPMzq/3XcDmJ1I9EojG9G0ypgkYw4MBv8VGeGRuQgYFHNe2jqM4hSKbMksCzx\n'+
                                'jSfzPhQBCnHroXEr/izYPWgh2m73737TYMHN5UVp9Kt/D1Kg/CUu6SDB6L6hbSYK\n'+
                                'YkWwifBtPzNcpF9cy7DPVaFGEeCkBroy86VcoQ/cVR7Vk8ECQQDapO2ve9Y332al\n'+
                                'iW7+2rFxSOeXwdofAlGpv378rAUIWrkGH11a4AtXInaPlty3td225IE6SyJu6trU\n'+
                                '4ookVNtZAkEAyikwrR6fDOqBPNrVKclfLjdFdfOhVIgdDXcD9lUhmcLJxF9NPKAW\n'+
                                'cVeCloFuw8eaHv8h2SrUt2itTw/N3ERY/QJAXP8XhbNTezJPM4uQJWAZZwjOUJMI\n'+
                                'VnYjC+NCfPAht9r2pa8DgxqWWDp1WT+eo5j8M8VfXc8FV04XQ8MTZL6fCQJBAKCY\n'+
                                'RCDiuHrsN6p+NOQzIjd2lOl0lu6uClZN+4nOaxjY0qv7AUJt8iYr3INvYuyIPfjt\n'+
                                'uJfqHH1u3G54IZMfgIkCQHBNzxAMO1upPNl5pbzw8KZyNavk9F+uYa3M54cpIw2H\n'+
                                'uO34E31dml3/77FAaCe8lIo2ezs+nbYVC2nNQZmGtGs=\n'+
                                '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----');
            var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(test.m_Item2);
            console.log(uncrypted);

            var base64Key = uncrypted;
            var baseiv = uncrypted;
            var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(baseiv);

            var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64Key);


            var decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(response, key, {
                                    keySize: 128 / 8,
                                    iv: iv,
                                    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                                    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                                } );

            var decryptedText = decryptedData.toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );

            document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src","data:image/png;base64,"+decryptedText);
        };

        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question title so more people find this answer if they're looking for encryption?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to utilize multiprocessing in the browser, but browser support is pretty porous, and it will probably feel like a hack. You'll need to use a browser that creates a new process for each tab, and that supports shared worker threads. So basically, Chrome.

Using a Shared Worker object will allow multiple tabs or Windows to share data. So all you need to do is create a script that decrypts a portion of the image (decrypt.js), and sends the clear data back through the worker. Then, have your main script open a few new tabs running decrypt.js and send each one the data to crunch.

However, there are still nuances. The message passing across processes will impact performance for large objects since they must be copied. This can be relieved using Transferable Objects; essentially, you'll have to manage formatting your data into an array buffer and back again.

Also, the browser will probably give those tabs a low execution priority or stop them all together, depending on the implementation. In that case, you'll have to create a worker thread that posts a message to the main thread at regular intervals, for each tab.

This is all assuming that the encryption algorithm you're using can be done in parallel, and that the JSEncrypt library supports it...

My suggestion: decrypt in a standard, dedicated worker thread and show a loading bar. 10 seconds isn't that bad when there's something pretty to look at ;)